# Propper related objects creation within Django modelform

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Suppose there are two models: **Author** and **Book**.
Sure enough **Book** has a foreign key to an **Author**.
There is a create view in which user gives a name of the author and uploads a file with the list of books it has.

So I am trying to figure out the best way to create a form.
Right now I have:

```
class AddForm(ModelForm):
     books = FileField()
     class Meta:
          model = Author

     def clean_books(self):
          return [book.strip() for book in self.cleaned_data['books'].file]
```

The problem is where should I put the actual creation of **Books** model objects? Looks like it should be in a `save` method, something like:

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    author = super().save(commit=True)
    Book.objects.bulk_create([Book(author=author, title=book.title, ...) for book in self.cleaned_data['books']])
    return author
```

But is it ok? What really annoys me is the `commit` argument. It's totally ignored and it may confuse others if they supply `commit=False`. How do I take into account commit argument and do not break the logic?

Answer (score 1):

Take look at [inline formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets). Using them you can add bunch of inline forms inside your main form. That formset will handle for you all processing of data and saving `Book` instances into database. It's like inline in django admin.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not understand how to use it with my concrete example. Can you provide an example given I use CreateView CBV?